# MS Access crashes on error

Tags: ms-access, error-handling

I wrote a little SQL command to correct a field in a table. Since it was so small (and maybe I got a little arrogant) I didn't run it even once, and just put it into an update package for a different user.

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
On Error GoTo errhandler


SQL = "UPDATE Table1 SET Name = 'Calender' WHERE Name = 'Clalender'"
CurrentDb.Execute

errhandler:
Exit Sub
```

That's why I didn't notice it should have been

```
CurrentDb.Execute (SQL)
```

When the user started this command, Access said something like "Critical Error" and closed.

How come the error handling didn't catch that error? And why didn't Access tell me there was something missing when I wrote it? Usually it's quite pedantic about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
CurrentDb.Execute
```

will not compile.

> Compile error: Argument not optional.

Your victim ;) must have hit the error when they tried to run the code, which triggered an "on-the-fly" compilation. Error trapping in your code would not handle that because your code never got a chance to run (because it wouldn't compile).

In other words, Access *would* have gotten all pedantic on you if you had tried to run (or at least compile) your code.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to compact and repair the database.

If that does not work, create a new empty database and import all the objects from the problematic database. Perhaps, you can import a few objects each time to determine which is the corrupted object (if any. Sometimes Access have this behavior and there isn't any bad object).

Comment: the database is ok. after a restart everything was still in its place. i was just wondering why my errorhandling didnt work.